# How do I access sub view controllers from Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

This seems like such a dumb question but I can't quite figure it out:

My storyboard looks like: `TabBarController` -> `Navigation Controller` -> `Table View Controller 1` -> `Table View Controller 2`.

This code is located in the `Tab Bar Controller` and I am trying to access `Table View Controller 2`

So the way that I understand it, this gets me the `Navigation Controller`

```
let tempNavVC = self.viewControllers?[0] as! UINavigationController
```

And this should get me the `Table View Controller 2` as I think it is index 1 of `tempNavVC`'s `viewControllers` array.

```
let secondVC = tempNavVC.viewControllers[1] as! TableViewController2
```

However, it is clearly not because I am getting:

> 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI
>   objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _What_ "errors" are you getting? (And you don't really have those backticks in your code, do you? Show your _real_ code!)

Comment: oops, that's just formatting error when trying to write up this question

Comment: Good, now also paste in the error message, please.

Comment: Updated with error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The storyboard describes relationships, but it does not describe runtime reality. A pushed view controller (like your second table view controller) is something that *can* exist if the push happens, but it is not necessarily something that *does* exist.

Thus, `tempNavVC.viewControllers[1]` will work if the navigation view controller *has* two children, i.e. if the second table view is in fact showing in the interface right now. But if only the first of its table view controller children is there, it won't (because the second one has not yet been instantiated and pushed onto the navigation view controller).

Comment: This is a great help.  So if I'd like to pass down data for `Table View Controller 2` to display, I should pass it down one step into `Table View Controller1` first?

Comment: Common practice in this situation is that vc1 hands data to vc2. This makes sense because vc1 has a reference to vc2 through its `prepareForSegue`. — Involving the tab bar controller is not so clearcut; I'm unclear why it has data at all. I'm not saying that's wrong, I'm just saying that various designs are possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
let navC = tabbarController.viewcontrollers[0] as! UINavigationController
let tableC: UIViewController = navC.rootViewController
```

....

Comment: `let tableC: UIViewController = navC.rootViewController`